# How to specify table for BeautifulSoup to find?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab the table on this page https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=139755 under the Net Price expandable object. I've gone through tutorials for BS4, but I get so confused by the complexity of the html in this case that I can't figure out what syntax and which tags to use.

Here's a screenshot of the table and html I'm trying to get:

[image]

This is what I have so far. How do I add other tags to narrow down the results to just that one table?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=139755')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
soup = soup.find(id="divctl00_cphCollegeNavBody_ucInstitutionMain_ctl02")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Once I can parse that data, I will format into a dataframe with pandas.

Comment: if you want to use pandas then maybe you should use `pandas.read_html(url)` which should find all `<table>` in HTML and create list with many `DataFrame` (every `<table>` in seperated `DataFrame`)

Comment: The table is `soup.find(id="divctl00_cphCollegeNavBody_ucInstitutionMain_ctl02 table.tabular")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'd probably just use pandas to retrieve all tables then index in for appropriate

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=139755')[10]
print(table)
```

If you are worried about future ordering you could loop the tables returned by read_html and test for presence of a unique string to identify table or use bs4 functionality of :has , :contains (bs4 4.7.1+) to identify the right table to then pass to read_html or  continue handling with bs4

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=139755')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:has(td:contains("Average net price"))')))
print(table)
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't realize I could use pd.read_html and the string search part is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ok , maybe this can help you , I add pandas

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=139755')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find("div", {"id": "divctl00_cphCollegeNavBody_ucInstitutionMain_ctl02"})
table = div.findAll("table", {"class": "tabular"})[1]

l = []
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    if td:
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        l.append(row)    

df=pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["AVERAGE NET PRICE BY INCOME","2015-2016","2016-2017","2017-2018"])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic script to scrape that first table in that accordion:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=139755#netprc"

page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

parent_table = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'netprc'})

desired_table = parent_table.find('table')

print(desired_table.prettify())
```

I assume you only want the values within the table so I did an overkill version of this as well that will combine the column names and values together:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=139755#netprc"

page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

parent_table = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'netprc'})
desired_table = parent_table.find('table')

header_row = desired_table.find_all('th')

headers = []
for header in header_row:
    header_text = header.get_text()
    headers.append(header_text)

money_values = []
data_row =desired_table.find_all('td')
for rows in data_row:
    row_text = rows.get_text()
    money_values.append(row_text)

for yrs,money in zip(headers,money_values):
    print(yrs,money)
```

This will print out the following:

```
 Average net price
2015-2016 $13,340
2016-2017 $15,873
2017-2018 $16,950
```